# Design: Questions marked answered not distinct enough

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In your user profile list of your questions and the indicators for those you've marked as answered is not distinct enough from the unanswered questions.

The difference currently is basically a teal or a lighter teal for the text color. Traditionally the questions marked answered have a background color with reverse text while the unanswered questions are merely text.

[image]

^^ Those are all marked answered but one would be hard-pressed to tell.

Comment: I was ahead of you there ;) http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/890/bugs-new-site-five-minor-css-oddities

Comment: ahh but as requested.. one question per issue :)

Comment: Good point. No harm done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already fixed, will be live soon after the next production build

Comment: Way better Stéphane! Nice work.